# How to move items to folder based on first three characters of file Mac

Tags: macos, applescript, finder

I am trying to move files such as

`68 - Logo - Standard (B&W).pdf`

to the corresponding folder which would be something like

`68 - Oak Hill xyz`

These folders are in a sorted logos folder, which has all of the folders in a list like

`68 - Oak Hill Xyz
284 - Juniata Hill Xyz
294 - Highland Hill xyz`

I have found multiple versions of different AppleScripts to accomplish this, but they seem to be outdated or no longer work properly when I try them. I have also tried this terminal script to no avail.

`find . -type f -name “*pdf” -maxdepth 1 -exec bash -c 'mkdir -p “${0%%-*}”’ {} \; \
-exec bash -c 'mv "$0" "${0%%_*}"' {} \;`

These pdf files are also in a different folder than the corresponding numbered folders are in.

Comment: Can you give more details on the folder structure?

Comment: Sure. The folder I would like to place these files into is Under Downloads > Logos > Sorted Logos. The files I need to move from are under Downloads > Logos > BW PDF.

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you want (making a few assumptions...):

```
property destination_folders : "/Users/<your name>/Downloads/Logos/BW PDF"

set files_to_sort to choose file with multiple selections allowed

tell application "System Events"
    repeat with a_file in files_to_sort
        set prefix to text 1 through 3 of (get name of a_file)
        set destination to my folderStartingWith(prefix)
        if destination is not false then
            move a_file to destination
        end
    end repeat
end tell

on folderStartingWith(txt)
    tell application "System Events"
        try
            set target_folder to first folder of folder destination_folders whose name begins with txt
        on error errstr
            display dialog errstr
            return false
        end try
        return target_folder
    end tell
end folderStartingWith
```

Just substitute your user_name where it says  in the first line, run the script, and select the files you want to process in the dialog that appears. This will present an error message and skip over any files that do not have corresponding folders.

This does not follow folder hierarchies (though could be modified to do so). It could also be adapted into a droplet, folder action, or finder service if this is something that you have to do regularly.